# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in android studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

**Before anyone marks this as a duplicate**, allow me to make a few distinctions between my issue and the other similar posts:

- I get this "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in android studio" error with **only 1** project, all others will build and run without issue
- There are no other instances of Java/Eclipse running on my computer as far as I can tell, I've combed through my Task Manager upwards of 25 times now
- I'm running this on Android Studio in Kotlin, not in Eclipse in Java

I've continuously run into this issue and I have no idea what to do. I've tried:

- closing all other open programs and restarting Android Studio
- restarting my computer
- uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio
- invalidating cache and restarting
- pulling a fresh version from the git repo

None of which works. I'm at my wits end, any help would be appreciated.

The only error output I get in my build log is:
`An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in android studio`

**Edit:**
Here's a screenshot of the build log
[image: buildlog]
*computer is in french*

Comment: What precisely are you doing in Android Studio? (running the app on a device or emulator? Build APKs? something else?) Can you build the app using `gradlew` at the command line? Is there anything unusual about this project? Which Android Studio version are you using? "The only error output" -- what non-error output precedes it?

Comment: @CommonsWare  
1. I'm working on an Android App (sorry for the vague answer, not sure what your question is asking specifically)  
2. Running the app on an AVD Pixel 3 Emulator  
3. Only difference between this and my previous projects is that this one is being worked on in a team via git  
4. version 4.1.1  
5. quite literally nothing precedes it, it's just that single line in red text

Comment: "sorry for the vague answer, not sure what your question is asking specifically" -- what item in the Studio menu or toolbar are you using that is triggering the build? "Running the app on an AVD Pixel 3 Emulator 3" -- have you tried just building the APK? (Build > Build Bundles/APK(s) > Build APK(s) from the main menu). "quite literally nothing precedes it, it's just that single line in red text" -- right-click over the "Apollo" root element in that tree on the left and check "Show Warnings" and "Show Successful Steps" in the context menu, and see if that gives you more info.

Comment: The problem is that while I can see that error message in the source code, it's buried in some socket management code, and I don't know what socket it is referring to. If I had to guess, it is coming from a broken connection to the emulator. So, that's why I suggest trying to just build the APK -- if that works, that further suggests that it's at the deploy-to-emulator step that the problem arises. And, you might try deploying to a physical device, instead of an emulator, and see if that behaves differently.

Comment: @CommonsWare  
1. Whenever I open the project for the first time or click the play button, I get this error
2. truthfully, I'm still learning, so I'm not sure what building the APK does, but I've tried it and nothing noticeable occurred
3. I've enabled both "Show Warnings" and "Show Successful Steps" and still nothing else is displayed. The error seems to occur almost immediately after the build is attempted, "Gradle Daemon started in X s X ms" then the error message

Comment: @CommonsWare The strange thing is that my other teammates haven't encountered this issue at all. So I'm inclined to believe this has something to do with the install of Android Studio on my device. However, I haven't been able to learn a way to truly full uninstall the program. Whenever I try (including attempting to delete any additional android studio files), on re-install it still manages to have my user settings. Truthfully, if there is a way to HARD uninstall the program, at this point I'd rather just do that and re-install, the code is backed up on the repo, so I won't lose anything